# Create custom class UI in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

In VBA, a UserForm is just a custom class (with some events and properties), and with a built in user interface. I too would like to make a custom class with a built in user interface, only it's not the same one used by userforms.

For example, say I want to make a calculator user-interface. I'll need some image elements for the calculator background and the buttons, some textbox for the screen, and then some button elements to listen for user clicks. I then link these all in some way to a class which holds all of the event listeners and the initialisation/close code to make the GUI actually appear

My question is where do I start if I want to design something like this?

#### Method

One way I can think of is like this (in Excel):

- Design the look of the interface in an image editor
- Export the various elements as individual picture files, and save them to a location/ on a hidden worksheet
- Create a class in VBA which has code to piece the various image elements together, i.e to place each in a pre-specified location relative to one another
- Cobble together any of the remaining *interactive* parts (buttons, output textbox etc.) using activeX controls, which are invisible and positioned over their respective image elements
- Initialise these controls with event listeners in my class

*That* I can relatively easily do. But it has the following key limitations that I can think of:

#### Problems*

1. In terms of events, I am constrained to whatever the activeX control has by default

Because my approach constructs the interface from image elements, *from VBA's point of view*, these would be `Shape` objects (to support transparency - rounded edges - as activeX image controls don't support this). These don't raise any events, so if I want to detect, say, when the user hovers over the calculator frame, I'll either have cover it with invisible activeX labels, or make API calls to see what the mouse is doing. The first is infeasible for complex shapes, the latter adds a whole load of additional complexity. Ideally I'd like some way of specifying which elements raise which events from a list of those available to me.

2. Resizing/redesigning at runtime

If my interface is built from image elements, I cannot easily change the design at runtime. If say, I want to resize the frame element of my GUI, then standard raster format images (png, jpeg etc.) will become blurred, vector images (which Excel now provides limited support to) don't by default have the rules like `If the frame height is changed, stretch the sides but do not stretch the toolbar at the top`. Changing colour of elements is something I'd like to support too, but that is very hard to do with images, `recolor` is an option, but only available to MSPublisher.

3. Memory/ filesize

The majority of the graphical elements of my interface would probably be fairly simple designs. Filesizewise this lends itself much better to a vector image format than a raster format, but activeX controls do not support that as a background. So filesize goes up, and probably some lag introduced, relative to a simple button added to a userform.

**nb these are only for context, so can be skipped if you like, or I can elaborate further on them if need be*

### Conclusion

I don't want to use userforms because they already have some of the interface set in concrete - the frame, the rectangular shape, the specific event listeners for specific elements. I could possibly design what I want *within* a userform, but I'd like a blank canvas in terms of the appearance. I'm sure there must be a better way to design custom interfaces to be controlled with VBA class like a userform can?

I have a vague idea that Visual Studio might be useful, but I don't even know what tutorials to search for. I can only so far find instructions on Windows Forms (which I don't want for the same reasons as I don't want a userform), or Excel addins (which interact with Excel but don't seem to have their own customizable interface). Neither is quite what I'm after, so I think I need to start with a human being to understand the problem and point me in the right direction.

Comment: This is off topic for many reasons. Sorry

Comment: @Dave I thought as much, it didn't belong on SO because it's not a specific programming question, I thought it was better for SuperUser because it's *about* software, but I can see why it could be off topic. Any suggestions for a better place to post? I'm at a level of understanding where I don't even know what to search for to get started!

Comment: Seems too broad, maybe lessen this down into one simple question and post on SO. Pick somewhere to start and take baby steps one-by-one. You have a whole story here you wrote so I would suggest simplifying your question and breaking this up into smaller questions that are more specific summing it up. Google and YouTube are your friends and as you do research and dive into one aspect, other aspects should gain more clarity and this will help you do further research or explain your question more clearly.